# How to adjust gdaltransform ground control point weighting control?

Tags: proximity, nearest-neighbor, ground-control, plss, gdaltransform

Let's take a 6 x 6 mile US [PLSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_Land_Survey_System) township, and house numbers 800 to a mile. Using gdaltransform, given the coordinates of each section corner as our ground control points (`-gcp 4800 4800 lon lat` for the NE corner of section 1, for example), we can convert any lon,lat to an address, or vice versa.

So far so good. But I just want gdaltransform to use the closest four -gcps, so as to not let neighboring PLSS sections influence, even slightly, the calculations for this section.

Sure, I could just give gdaltransform a maxium of four -gcps per run. But then I would need 36 runs instead of one.

So is there any way to infuence how seriously gdaltransform takes farther away points?

E.g., if my -gcps consist of Boston GCPs and New York GCPs, will one still influence address queries in the far away other place?

Seems all this is not documented on https://gdal.org/programs/gdaltransform.html ... except maybe `-order`? Maybe I need a PiecewiseAffineTransform... Hmm, the [-tps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin_plate_spline) option does mention piecewise...

I just want the program to, you might say, use the [upper left image](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Catmull-Clark_subdivision_4_planes_levels_0-3.png#/media/File:Catmull-Clark_subdivision_4_planes_levels_0-3.png) model, and not the three other images.

I see https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/alg/gdaltransformer.cpp has more parameters...

Answer (score 0):

You sir, can only blame yourself for giving gdaltransform more GCPs than you really want it to use (and then asking here how to clean up the mess!)

You should just "control yourself" and only give it the four corners of the relevant section, even if this means you need to run gdaltransform more than once. At least you can group your runs to get it down to just 36 if you really want.